# Where and how could find On this day API to get date and facts about events in science, inventions and business?

Tags: api

I know about Wikipedia API or other 'On This day API', but it's wide items.

I need information only about events in science, inventions and business and people in these niches, and these info sould be links with calendare (date and month). I tried to find them but while without success.

While I'm just trying customise Wiki API and Googled it.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a SPARQL query that gets all Wikidata elements that have that month/day as a value for any property.

Then you would need to filter, for instance by allowing only items that are an instance of any sub-class of "business", or only items that are an instance of "human" with an occupation property whose value is any subclass of "[scientist](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q901)", etc.